# Why does my tag jump outside the grid area?

Tags: html, css

I have a school project where I am trying to make this website, but my html tag just jumps outside the css-grid. How can I fix this? Keep in mind that I am new to html/css so please try to answer in a simple way.

Here is a picture of how it looks:
[image: Here is a picture of how it looks]

Here is my code:

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#grid_wrapper{
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 3fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 100px 100px 200px 200px 1fr;
    grid-template-areas: 
    "hdr hdr hdr nav"
    "img img img img"
    "img img img img"
    "img img img img"
    "asd art art asd"
    ;
}

#rubrik{
    grid-area: hdr;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Välkommen till Härmanö</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style_start.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="grid_wrapper">
        <header id="rubrik">
            <h1>Välkommen till Härmanö</h1>
        </header>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your issue is with the "asd" areas.

They have the same name, but they are not next to each other.

You can fix it changing those area names.

```
grid-template-areas:    "hdr hdr hdr nav"
                        "img img img img"
                        "img img img img"
                        "img img img img"
                        "asd1 art art asd2";
```